# How to install video player in iOS Simulator?

Tags: ios-simulator

1. I am using iOS simulator 6 and platform version as 8.3.
2. I need to install video player for iOS simulator.
3. I tried to install video player, but it shows as invalid Url.
4. I have attached the screen shot for reference.[image]

Comment: Please be more specific regarding what you actually need.  It looks like you're trying to install RealPlayer in the sim.  That definitely won't work.  Why are you trying to do that?  The sim is a development tool; there are frameworks available to help you create your own video player.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia, I want to install any video player. I am new to this.I don't know how to install player in iOS simulator.

Comment: *WHY* do you want to install a video player?  What is your use case?  As I mentioned, it's a developer tool, not an end user tool.  The point of the simulator is to allow one to create a video player, not to install one that already exists.  You need to have the source code to build what you want in order to install it.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia, I need to write test case for video related article. When, I tried to open a video, it shows message as sorry video cannot be displayed. So I don't have any player.

Comment: If you visit a site that uses HTML5 video, it'll work.  Your screenshot shows you're trying to use RealPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a simulator app bundle available, you can run:

```
xcrun simctl install booted /path/to/the/videoPlayer.app
```

Comment: I have given this  command in terminal "xcrun simctl install booted QuickTimePlayer.app". But, it throws error as  
An error was encountered processing the command (code=22):
Failed to install the requested application
The bundle identifier of the application could not be determined.
Ensure that the application's Info.plist contains a value for CFBundleIdentifier.

Comment: Yeah, QuickTimePlayer.app is an OS X Application.  You would need to install an iOS Simulator App into the sim.

Comment: I have given the command in terminal. It throws above error message. Is there any other way to install it in simulator?

Comment: I think you are completely missing the point.  The iOS Simulator allows you to run applications that are built for the iOS Simulator.  You can't just install an OS X application in it and expect it to do something.